# Adding external dependency to Gradle task

Tags: java, build, gradle

I am on a project witch develops an adapter utility for a legacy closed-source library which is treated as black box and due to licence agreements cannot be shipped along with the adapter utility.

In order to build the project the library needs to be in the class path which is no problem as long as I am using an IDE (IDEA in my case) but how can I tell Gradle having this dependency during building without adding it directly to build.gradle?

Comment: Why can't you declare the dependency on the library in `build.gradle`? Where does your IDE get the library from?

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser In the IDE I have declared as global library. I do not want to add it into the build.gradle because I do not want to check-in the binaries of the legacy library into the repository and without checking it in there is no common folder to define where the library could be taken from.

Comment: If there is no common folder, how do people set this up in their IDE? If you really want everyone to set this up on their own, they'll have to declare the dependency in their `~/.gradle/init.gradle`. Or they set the path in their `~/.gradle/gradle.properties`, which is then used to declare the dependency in `build.gradle`.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser I decided to follow your idea adding it via file system. Thanks for your help!